# Format a day in a week based on a number with date-fns

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

Using `date-fns`, how do I use a number from `0` to `6` to format such a number using the [`format` function](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/format)?

The module heavily uses numbers `0` to `6` to enumerate a day in a week (for exmaple, [`startOfWeek`](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/startOfWeek) expects a `weekStartsOn` as a number between `0` and `6`), but I cannot find a way to use that number to format its name.

Answer (score 0):

A kinda obvious and weird workaround that I've come up with is to use an aribrarly chosen Sunday and just `addDays` from there, and `format` that. I'm not sure if there are some weird edge cases where this might not work.

```
const anArbitrarySunday = new Date(2017, 9, 22)
return format(addDays(anArbitrarySunday, number), 'dd')
```